# Price Earnings Ratio

Tags: investing, price-earnings-ratio

OK so struggling to get my head around why a high price earnings ratio is preferable to a low P.E. . If there is a big gap between a company's share price and its earnings per share surely that would drive potential investors away?

Comment: With a name like yours, I'm surprised you'd struggle with anything ;).

Answer (score 3):

The P/E ratio is a measure of historic (the previous financial year) earnings against the current share price.

If the P/E is high, this means that the market perceives a big increase in future earnings per share.  In other words, the perception is that this is a fast growing company.  Higher earnings may also equate to big increases in dividends and rapid expansion.

On the other hand, if the P/E is low, then there is a perception that either earnings per share are decreasing or that future growth in earnings is negligible.  In other words, low P/E equates to a perception of low future growth and therefore low prospects for future payout increases - possibly even decreases.

The market is (rightly) usually willing to pay a premium for fast growing companies.

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks us to explain why a false statement is true.  From the point of view of an investor, a high price to earnings ratio **is not necessarily desirable**.

From the point of view of an investor, a **desirable stock** is one that is likely to provide future dividends or price increases that more than compensates for the risk of the stock.  This information cannot be inferred from the P/E ratio.

So what does the P/E ratio tell us? The P/E ratio measures a stock's *current* price (i.e., the market's belief about its future earnings) divided by its recent *past* earnings.  A high ratio means the market thinks earnings in the future will be higher than they are now and have therefore bid the price up.  These can thought of as **expensive** stocks, and are often called "growth" stocks because their price is driven by the market's belief in future growth.

Some individual high P/E stocks do live up to or exceed the market's expectation, but there's no evidence that this happens enough that they are more desirable as a group than low P/E stocks. If anything, the empirical evidence goes the other way.